# How can i get input stream to a program running with nohup and & in shell

Tags: linux, shell, background-process, nohup

I am running program with 
nohup add.sh &

This scripts take inputs at the runtime from the console.
how can i get hold of the input stream to this process so that i can pass the 2 numbers?

Thanks

Comment: [Pipe/send command to process running on nohup that accepts input from STDIN](http://superuser.com/questions/224599/pipe-send-command-to-process-running-on-nohup-that-accepts-input-from-stdin)

Answer (score 1):

That depends of how your script works, but generally you can send input to another command via a pipe:

```
  nohup echo "This is my input" | add.sh &
```

However I don't know if you can do it with more than 1 argument. You may need to enhance your add.sh script in order to accept and use parameters if they are provided.